# How to sum the difference between two ranges only when adjacent cells are non-blank?

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the difference between two ranges, but only when adjacent cells are both non-blank. For example, the following data set would return a value of zero...

```
   X    Y
1  100  100
2       200
3  200  300
```

Without adding the condition that any two laterally adjacent cells must be non-blank, the result would be -200.

The solution would, ideally, be a modification of the following array operation...

```
=sum(B2:B4-C2:C4)
```

Any help provided would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can add if, and blanks are considered as 0 I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just found a solution that seems to work... 
=SUM(IF(B2:B4<>"", B2:B4-C2C4,0)) + Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Please post it as an answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution that seems to work...

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B4<>"", B2:B4-C2C4,0)) + Ctrl + Shift + Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this *normal* formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B4-C2:C4)*ISNUMBER(B2:B4)*ISNUMBER(C2:C4))
```